# Position of a multiset lower_bound iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, multiset

Assume, I have a multiset A = {0, 1, 1, 1, 2}. If a do the following operation:

```
multiset<int>::iterator it = A.lower_bound(2)
```

It  returns a iterator. I can easily print its value. But is there any way to know its position? i mean it will return 4.

Comment: You can use [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) to get an offset from `A.begin()`.

Comment: i am looking for some fast alternative. as far as i know complexity of distance() is O(n). Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Yes it's O(n) for that type of iterators ([bidirectional iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator)), and no there's really no faster way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance)

```
#include <iterator>
#include <set>

int main() 
{
    multiset<int> A = { 0, 1, 1, 1, 2 };
    multiset<int>::iterator it = A.lower_bound( 2 );
    size_t dist = distance( A.begin(), it );
}
```

Comment: Is their any fast alternative of this?

Comment: @Ihzaz Abrar I know no other